# Is there any Poweshell Script or az command to get the list of Products and its Subscription IDs for API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We are using the Azure API Management Product subscription id in our Front End applications and there is no track on which frontend application is using which id as the product is having multiple subscription id and the one API has multiple products attached to it.
Sometimes we need to add the header policies where the front-end developer will give us the subscription id they are using and it becomes difficult to check in the portal UI to get the name of the product from the subscription id.

Looking for a Powershell script or az command which can give the list of products with subscription id so that it will be easy and useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

List products: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementproduct?view=azps-5.5.0

List subscriptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementsubscription?view=azps-5.5.0

Get subscription key: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementsubscriptionkey?view=azps-5.5.0

APIM az reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Using below Powershell commands I am getting the list of subscriptions but it is not including the Primary and Secondary Keys of the subscription.


$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" -ServiceName "apim-name"



Get-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $apimContext

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this.   Unfortunately, I don't know yet how to extract the secret keys of the apim subscriptions, which do not appear here:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
  Connect-AzAccount
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'my-playground'

$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "my- 
  playground" -ServiceName "my-apim-playground"
Get-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $apimContext | Format-Table - 
  Property Name, SubscriptionId
```